# Не могу получить значение куки JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookie

Мне нужно из куки получить значение id пользователя. 
Вот функция которой я читаю куки

```
function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
        {
            var results = document.cookie.match ( '(^|;) ?' + cookie_name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)' );

            if ( results )
                return ( unescape ( results[2] ) );
            else
                return null;
        }

console.log(get_cookie('user-session'));
```

В итоге эта функция возвращает мне такое значение `j:"5e575c7ab7deb71fb8eb448e"`. 
Как мне получить только то что находится между двойными ковычками `5e575c7ab7deb71fb8eb448e`?

Comment: И кстати метод "unescape" устарел. Лучше использовать "decodeURI" или "decodeURIComponent".

Answer (score 0):

Если получаемая строка всегда содержит `j:" ... "`, то просто вытащить подстроку вот так: `results[2].slice(3,-1)`

Comment: Я так уже пробовал. Не помогает. Метод `slice` обрезает ненужные символы и добавляет 2 новых впереди значения и 2 символа после значения. Получается он берёт такое значение `j:"5e575c7ab7deb71fb8eb448e"`, а возвращает такое `A"5e575c7ab7deb71fb8eb448e%2`.

Comment: Какая-то мистика. Метод `slice ` ничего не добавляет. Можно удивить код с использованием метода?